# How to add const after item. instead of name from data?

Tags: javascript

So I have a piece of code that creates a chart and have the code below to add the data into it. I get the data from an api in json format. Now I have a drop down menu when the user chooses the signal and so where it says temperature I need to put the "signal" const that I have but I cant because it thinks its part of the json which it isnt. So how do I add the const after the "item." so it is recognized as a variable?

```
const grab = async () => {
const time = document.getElementById("time").value;
const signal = document.getElementById("signal").value;


var url = "api url goes here just not showing it " + signal + "/" + time;
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    method: "GET",
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    success: function(datafunc) {
                        resolve(datafunc)
                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                        reject(error);
                    }
                })
        })
        }
        const createChart = async () => {

        $(document).ready(function() {
            grab().then((datafunc) => {
                console.log('Recieved our data', datafunc);
                const xtime = [];
                const ydata = [];

                try {
                    datafunc.forEach((item) => {
                        xtime.push(item.date_time)
                        ydata.push(item.signal)
                    });

                    const chartdata = {
                        labels: [...xtime],
                        datasets: [{
                            label: name,
                            data: ydata
                        }],


                    };

                    const ctx = $("#choiceChart");

                    const barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                        type: 'bar',
                        data: chartdata

                    });

                } catch (error) {
                    console.log('Error', error)
                }

            })
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hi Jaakko, please add some information, like the API Result, what is `datafunc`, and can you explain better what is this "signal" const? Maybe explaining what you tried and didn't work or explaining precisely where you're stuck?

Comment: @leonardfactory So the api result is {date_time: "2020-04-24T16:00:00.000Z", humidity_in: "43.97"} the "humidity_in" changes depending on what is selected like temperature or rain for example and that is the signal. datafunc is just part of the whole function which creates and updates the chart. In my html I have a <select> where the the options are different signals like the temperature. And so throught getElementbyId the signal is equal to whatever the user chose. I have tried doing .signal and .getElementbyId within the foreach function.

Comment: Please, post full code (editing your post if possibile). Thank you

Comment: @leonardfactory Done. The added code is code that grabs the data and creates the chart